# Program inputs only one line into text file

Tags: c++, file, text, input, output

My program inputs numbers from a text file only once. I also noticed that last line of given numbers was used in calculations. Is it bad if I'm trying to do that in a while loop? If so, how else could I do that?

The number are:

5
100 1 20
120 1 45
90 1 05
105 1 25
100 1 35

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double d,a,b,c,g=0;
    ifstream file("Text.txt");
    if(file.is_open())
    {
        file >> d;
        cout << d << endl;
        while(file >> a >> b >> c)
        {
            cout << left << setw(3) << a << " " << b << " " << c << endl;
            g=a/(b*60+c);
            ofstream files("Result.txt");
            files << "Speed: " << g << " m/s" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Something went wrong with given numbers, it shouldve been like this : in 1st line there is 1 number, in all other lines there are 3 numbers.

Comment: So, what exactly is your question?

Comment: I wish your lecture will teach you to use the debugger

Comment: This program inputs only one line in "Result.txt" instead of 5. Its probably because im doing that in a while loop ?

Comment: Ok, i found my problem. I needed to add ios::app in ofstream. Works fine now.

Comment: But, I think there is another better way than doing this. Could anyone give me an example ?

Comment: @HallNovice Yes, there is - just open output file outside of the loop. Without `ios::app` it just gets cleared on each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with this line *inside* the loop

```
        ofstream files("Result.txt");
```

It creates a *new* file each time you read from the input. So it will only contain the output for the last input.

If you move that line to just before the `while`, you will get all your output in the same file.